# Collapsing section ranges in titlesec page headers

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

I'm attempting to use dictionary-style ranges for page headers using `titlesec`, but I'm running into a problem when trying to collapse them if there's only a single range on a given page.

The [documentation](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) suggests this is possible, but is also stunningly vague:

> "Of
>   course, this example should be fine tuned to collapse the ranges if there is a single section in a page, but it gives a hint of how to get stunning headers."

Given the following code below, I'd like the header on the second page to say "3" rather than "3-3". Why doesn't `ifstrequal` work?

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\newpagestyle{pagestyle}{
  \sethead[\ifstrequal{\toptitlemarks\thesection}{\bottitlemarks\thesection}{\toptitlemarks\thesection}{\toptitlemarks\thesection---\bottitlemarks\thesection}]
  []
  []
  {}
  {}
  {\ifstrequal{\toptitlemarks\thesection}{\bottitlemarks\thesection}{\toptitlemarks\thesection}{\toptitlemarks\thesection---\bottitlemarks\thesection}}
  }
\pagestyle{pagestyle}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{}
\lipsum[1]
\section{}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. [titleps's documentation](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec)

> One of the disavantaged of the switching mechanism is that comparing a
> command from, say, the top marks and the botttom marks is not trivial.
> This macro just makes it simpler. If you want to compare the currect
> `\thesection` with that in the top mark, write:
>
> ```
> \ifsamemark\toptitlemarks\thesection{<true>}{<false>}
> ```

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\newpagestyle{pagestyle}{
  \sethead[\ifsamemark\toptitlemarks\thesection{\ifsamemark\bottitlemarks\thesection{\toptitlemarks\thesection}{\toptitlemarks\thesection---\bottitlemarks\thesection}}{\toptitlemarks\thesection---\bottitlemarks\thesection}]
  []
  []
  {}
  {}
  {\ifsamemark\bottitlemarks\thesection{\ifsamemark\toptitlemarks\thesection{\toptitlemarks\thesection}{\toptitlemarks\thesection---\bottitlemarks\thesection}}{\toptitlemarks\thesection---\bottitlemarks\thesection}}
  }
\pagestyle{pagestyle}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{}
\lipsum[1]
\section{}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```